# DateTime data, split into days

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

Currently I am splitting my data by subtracting days from DateTime.Now

```
GetVolumeByDate(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3), DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2))
GetVolumeByDate(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2), DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1))
GetVolumeByDate(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1), DateTime.Now))
```

This shows all data from the last 24 hours as today and the 24 hour period before that as yesterday. What I'm looking to do is split the days at midnight. So today is from the 12am until now and yesterday is from 12am to the 12am before. What is the simplest way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `DateTime.Today` instead of `DateTime.Now`

```
GetVolumeByDate(DateTime.Today.AddDays(-3), DateTime.Today.AddDays(-2))
```

`DateTime.Today` will return you the current date with time set to `00:00:00` or 12AM

Comment: Ah yes, and today would be GetVolumeByDate(DateTime.Today, DateTime.Now))

Answer (score 1):

Follow Habib's answer, but make sure that your last line of code is

```
GetVolumeByDate(DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1), DateTime.Now))
```

so that you get everything from now until yesterday's 12am.

Comment: Thanks Habib. I would have upvoted your answer and simply added my answer as a comment to your answer, but I do not have enough reputation to add comments yet.